# How can I create a data object using data elements?

Tags: abap

I want to know **what are the ways to create data object using data elements**?

Please help me find the proper way of creating a data object using data element.
In following example the `carr_id` is the data element.

- `DATA var LIKE carr_id`
- `DATA var TYPE REF TO carr_id`
- `PARAMETERS var TYPE carr_id`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for revert but this is the only one question but just want to which is correct in this options

Comment: You're welcome. However, it seems to me that your question is quite unclear, and very broad. I suggest you read the [ask] page, and take the [tour]. I'm sure you'll find them useful. The tips and explanations in those pages can help you write a question that others can answer.

Comment: thanks for help please check once again.

Comment: I made a few format changes in your question, please check to see if I understood your meaning correctly.

Comment: the first one is the most simple way to create a data object (i would call it a variable). but since it is not really clear to me what you are asking, i cannot give you a detailed answer.

Comment: just tell me from the above options which is the right way to create data obj ? or simply which is the right syntax from the options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE DATA d_object TYPE carr_id.
```

[Creating](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapcreate_data.htm) data object is pretty similar to declaring data objects.

All your statements have different meaning and only mine can be named as *creation of data object*.

```
DATA var LIKE carr_id.
```

This is **declaring** data object with the type alike previously created (sic!) data object. So your `carr_id` here should be data object (like `var`) not data element.

```
DATA var TYPE REF TO carr_id.
```

This is also a declaration of data object, but with the reference to `carr_id` data element. Here you declare [reference](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapdata_references.htm), not the flat data object. This is not the same.

And finally

```
PARAMETERS var TYPE carr_id.
```

is a special class of data objects called [selection parameters](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapparameters.htm) which serve special aim in selection screens. They shouldn't be used in other contexts.

So **neither** of your lines is a creation of a data object, they are pure **declarations**. Let's stick to proper terms.

Comment: i know this one thanks for reply can you please tell me from the above options which is the right one ?

Comment: see my explanation above